# Cocoa text editing component (for programmers)

Tags: cocoa, scintilla

Does anyone know if there is a code editing component for Cocoa, akin to Scintilla?

Or at least with following features: syntax coloring, indentation(, brace matching, whitespace showing, line wrapping)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a look at [smultron](http://sourceforge.net/projects/smultron/) (now defunct). If I remember correctly, it gives a decent overview on how to implement syntax highlighting in an NSTextView.